# Selinux is blocking Node service from starting via systemd unit file

Tags: node.js, npm, selinux

I am having a NodeJS application which runs fine when I start it manually with "npm run server". 
My app runs on Linux Centos8.
If I start the app as a service via the unit file below then it doesn't start when  setenforce=1 (selinux is enforcing). 
If I switch of selinux with setenforce=0 then the service starts when executing
"systemctl start translationtable"

This is mij unitfile which is located in  /etc/systemd/system/translationtable.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=TranslationtableService
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/nodejs/translationtable
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run server
Type=simple
User=sa-builder
Group=sa-builder
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the error I am getting after starting the service with:
systemctl status translationtable

```
translationtable.service - TranslationtableService
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/translationtable.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-05-17 10:32:04 CEST; 4s ago
  Process: 11815 ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run server (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 11815 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 17 10:32:04 ac8app01.myexample.nl systemd[1]: Started TranslationtableService.
May 17 10:32:04 ac8app01.myexample.nl systemd[1]: translationtable.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
May 17 10:32:04 ac8app01.myexample.nl systemd[1]: translationtable.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[root@ac8app01 translationtable]# vi /etc/systemd/system/translationtable.service
[root@ac8app01 translationtable]# systemctl status translationtable
  translationtable.service - TranslationtableService
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/translationtable.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-05-17 10:32:04 CEST; 8min ago
  Process: 11815 ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run server (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 11815 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 17 10:32:04 ac8app01.myexample.nl systemd[1]: Started TranslationtableService.
May 17 10:32:04 ac8app01.myexample.nl systemd[1]: translationtable.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
May 17 10:32:04 ac8app01.myexample.nl systemd[1]: translationtable.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

my app runs in
/opt/nodejs/translationtable

I tryed lot of things for example adding context to selinux as a lucky shot:

```
semanage fcontext -a --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/usr/bin/npm(/.*)?'
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /usr/bin/npm
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /usr/bin/npm

semanage fcontext -a --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/opt/nodejs/translationtable(/.*)?'
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /opt/nodejs/translationtable
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /opt/nodejs/translationtable
```

I also added the context of my  /var/log/audit/audit.log file where there are a lot of denys regarding selinux context things:

```
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1589712010.061:95): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=translationtable comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'^]UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712010.091:96): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1974 comm="(npm)" name="npm" dev="dm-0" ino=50690435 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1589712010.091:96): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=55c7f2a8e1e0 a1=55c7f29fc8f0 a2=55c7f2aaad70 a3=55c7f2852010 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1974 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="npm" exe="/usr/bin/node" subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 key=(null)^]ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=execve AUID="unset" UID="sa-builder" GID="sa-builder" EUID="sa-builder" SUID="sa-builder" FSUID="sa-builder" EGID="sa-builder" SGID="sa-builder" FSGID="sa-builder"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1589712010.091:96): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F6E6F6465002F7573722F62696E2F6E706D0072756E00736572766572
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712010.876:97): avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=1974 comm="npm" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1589712010.876:97): arch=c000003e syscall=10 success=yes exit=0 a0=84f68104000 a1=7b000 a2=5 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1974 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="npm" exe="/usr/bin/node" subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 key=(null)^]ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=mprotect AUID="unset" UID="sa-builder" GID="sa-builder" EUID="sa-builder" SUID="sa-builder" FSUID="sa-builder" EGID="sa-builder" SGID="sa-builder" FSGID="sa-builder"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1589712010.876:97): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F6E6F6465002F7573722F62696E2F6E706D0072756E00736572766572
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712011.007:98): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1974 comm="npm" path="/usr/bin/npm" dev="dm-0" ino=50690435 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1589712011.007:98): arch=c000003e syscall=332 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffcbba58e78 a2=100 a3=fff items=0 ppid=1 pid=1974 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="npm" exe="/usr/bin/node" subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 key=(null)^]ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=statx AUID="unset" UID="sa-builder" GID="sa-builder" EUID="sa-builder" SUID="sa-builder" FSUID="sa-builder" EGID="sa-builder" SGID="sa-builder" FSGID="sa-builder"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1589712011.007:98): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F6E6F6465002F7573722F62696E2F6E706D0072756E00736572766572
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712012.976:99): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1974 comm="npm" name="translationtable" dev="dm-0" ino=51493520 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1589712012.976:99): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=18 a0=ffffff9c a1=55e9fe518330 a2=90800 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1974 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="npm" exe="/usr/bin/node" subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 key=(null)^]ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=openat AUID="unset" UID="sa-builder" GID="sa-builder" EUID="sa-builder" SUID="sa-builder" FSUID="sa-builder" EGID="sa-builder" SGID="sa-builder" FSGID="sa-builder"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1589712012.976:99): proctitle="npm"
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712012.995:100): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1974 comm="npm" name="package.json" dev="dm-0" ino=51493542 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712012.995:100): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1974 comm="npm" path="/opt/nodejs/translationtable/package.json" dev="dm-0" ino=51493542 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1589712012.995:100): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=19 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffcbba556e8 a2=80000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1974 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="npm" exe="/usr/bin/node" subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 key=(null)^]ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=openat AUID="unset" UID="sa-builder" GID="sa-builder" EUID="sa-builder" SUID="sa-builder" FSUID="sa-builder" EGID="sa-builder" SGID="sa-builder" FSGID="sa-builder"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1589712012.995:100): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F6E6F6465002F7573722F62696E2F6E706D0072756E00736572766572
type=AVC msg=audit(1589712013.025:101): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1974 comm="npm" path="/opt/nodejs/translationtable/package.json" dev="dm-0" ino=51493542 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1589712013.025:101): arch=c000003e syscall=332 success=yes exit=0 a0=13 a1=55e9fc9d1339 a2=1000 a3=fff items=0 ppid=1 pid=1974 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="npm" exe="/usr/bin/node" subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 key=(null)^]ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=statx AUID="unset" UID="sa-builder" GID="sa-builder" EUID="sa-builder" SUID="sa-builder" FSUID="sa-builder" EGID="sa-builder" SGID="sa-builder" FSGID="sa-builder"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1589712013.025:101): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F6E6F6465002F7573722F62696E2F6E706D0072756E00736572766572
```

Nothing seems to work, I get a terrible headache of selinux.
Anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Check /var/log/messages for errors and suggestions.
Example:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/lib/systemd/systemd from <permission> on file <file>
For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l <some-id>
```

You can then run the *sealert* command to get detailed information about the problem and how to correct it.  (ausearch/audit2allow commands will be in the detailed info output from sealert )